# No Down-Time AWS + ECS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, elastic-load-balancer

guys.

I'm having a tiny issue which I haven't resolved so far.
The thing is this: I have a little application that runs on **ECS.**
To create the application, I create an **ASG** and on the **LaunchConfig** I register the instances to my **ECS Cluster**. Later, I put an **ALB** in front of my **ASG**, so that my app is available on Internet; all good so far. The problem comes when I want to roll an update on my **ECS** instances. I have a tiny downtime of like 20 seconds.

Well, it's not a complete downtime, but what happens is that my **LB** keeps sending requests to my **ECS1** while the update is rolling, so I got a pretty nice **502** on the browser. Of course, as soon as the update finishes, all goes good. The same **502** happens when my **ECS2** instance is being updated. If I refresh, I get a working app; if I refresh a second time, I get my **502** because, as I told, the **ALB** keeps sending requests to my **IN PROGRESS** (Rolling update) **ECS** instance.

So, I think I could dis-register the **ECS** instance while it's being uptaded, and then, when it's done, I could register it back. But I'm using **CloudFormation** to roll updates, and I don't really want to do things by hand.

My current Health Checks are done every **30** seconds for the Target Group to consider an instance as unhealthy and therefore, stop sending requests to it.

How could I accomplish it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, and I hope this may help someone in the future.

The key to avoid down-times is to register the LB with the ECS service, so that the LB will do the dirty work for us. Before the containers get updated, the LB will drain the instance, and therefore will not be sending requests to it. Meanwhile, there will be only one instance, which is a healthy one.

While the other instance drains, the LB only sends requests to the healthy one. Once the instance is drained, and dis-registered from the LB, the update rolls on the drained instance. Cool!! Isn't it?

So, once it finishes updating, the LB registers it back, waits till this passes the health checks, and then starts sending requests again.
After this one is updated, the LB is going to start doing the same thing with the one left (Drain it, update it, and register it back).

I will share with you the snippet that made the trick for me:

```
 Resources:
   ECSServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [ecs.amazonaws.com]
          Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      Path: /
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ecs-service
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ['elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer', 'elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterTargets',
              'elasticloadbalancing:Describe*', 'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer',
              'elasticloadbalancing:RegisterTargets', 'ec2:Describe*', 'ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress']
            Resource: '*'

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      DesiredCount: !Ref DesiredCount
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: nginx
          ContainerPort: '80'
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroupARN
      Role: !Ref 'ECSServiceRole'
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 100
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 50

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ...
```

Calling the LB from the service really does the trick. You should also consider setting a MinimumHealthyPercent to tell the service how many instances must always be up and running.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

There's a great [article on the AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/compute/how-to-automate-container-instance-draining-in-amazon-ecs/) that explain how to accomplish this. They even use CloudFormation for their exemple, so, no manual step involved.

They basically make use of Autoscaling Groups Lifecycle hook paired with SNS and Lambda to trigger connections draining when ASG instances are taken out of service. Best of all, this also works when CloudFormation triggers a rolling update.

[They open sourced the solution on GitHub](https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-cid-sample/), you can use the whole thing or just copy the interesting part as needed.

Comment: Looks like that's a pretty nice solution, I will for sure check it out on the future, when I have a bigger project, which will need to delete an entire instance to upgrade. For now, I just want to avoid deleting instances while rolling the update, because it's a small project, with just two instances; deleting them and create new ones on every update would be a pain. I found the answer exactly as I wanted. You can check it on the accepted answer.
Thanks a lot!